# How to deallocate memory in Java?

Tags: java, memory-management

In order to reduce `GC`-pressure I need to allocate some amount of off-heap memory as follows:

```
long sz;
//...
long pointer = sun.misc.Unsafe.getUnsafe().allocateMemory(sz);
```

But since it's unavailable for GC, I need to deallocate it later by hands. How? Is it possible to do?

Comment: Without knowing more about the real problem you are facing, I can only doubt that using `sun.misc.Unsafe` is the right thing to use.

Comment: @Axel In our context we didn't find a better way.

Comment: Whats wrong with the javadoc on Unsafe#allocateMemory ?

Comment: Get look on http://mydailyjava.blogspot.in/2013/12/sunmiscunsafe.html. Here you will get how to use freeMemory(). For your code is like sun.misc.Unsafe.getUnsafe().freeMemory(pointer);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really read its [javadoc](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/misc/Unsafe.java#l470) you won't get there:

> ```
> /**
>  * Allocates a new block of native memory, of the given size in bytes.  The
>  * contents of the memory are uninitialized; they will generally be
>  * garbage.  The resulting native pointer will never be zero, and will be
>  * aligned for all value types.  Dispose of this memory by calling {@link
>  * #freeMemory}, or resize it with {@link #reallocateMemory}.
>  *
>  * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the size is negative or too large
>  *         for the native size_t type
>  *
>  * @throws OutOfMemoryError if the allocation is refused by the system
>  *
>  * @see #getByte(long)
>  * @see #putByte(long, byte)
>  */
> public native long allocateMemory(long bytes);
> ```

So you need `unsafe.freeMemory(pointer)` to deallocate, or `unsafe.reallocateMemory(pointer)` to reallocate. Remember you can always access the sources of `sun.*` classes by visiting [openjdk's mercury repository](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/)